# osi model presentation layer formatting

Tags: networking, osi

So I've been reading for some time about this model. And I couldn't find an answer for the following question: I know that one of layer 6s jobs is to decide on a format for the data that it received from layer 7. For example .jpg. How does it know what format to add? 
Thanks !

Comment: You know that the presentation layer is almost never used in practice, right?

Comment: Yep, i still need to study it though..

Comment: You know that in the real world there is no such thing as a presentation layer? That this is just an abstract concept in an abstract model that corresponds to nothing in the real world? Tell your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

ISO's [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) is a reference model for communication (theoretical). According to it's guideleines, the [TCP/IP protocol suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) is developed (practical). Also, Presentation and Session layers are eliminated from actual TCP/IP protocol suite implementation. That being said, the answer to your question is, that one of the application layer protocol just passes the *.jpg file to transport layer as pure binary "data".

Comment: So you are saying that the content data is "transparent" to the presentation layer ?